# "Slack off" in the library

Tags: word-request

What is the word to describe when you sit in the library all day, not doing too much work, nor "slacking off" exactly, but browsing through pages without really thinking, and occasionally writing something down? Is there an English word to describe this exact situation?

Thanks!

Comment: You describe the patron as "without really thinking": about what they're reading, or about anything?  Are they perhaps **lost in thought** or **in a reverie**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no exact term for that (or at least I'm not aware of one).

The closest phrase without any ambiguity I can think of is "turning the pages and jotting down at times". You'll have to add *[jot down](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jot+down)* to convey the message.

A result from a Google Book search:

> "...that Prude is actually engaged in reading the books and is not just *turning the pages."* - The Idea of Justice

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

- wasting/killing time at the library
- idling at the library